# how t o get Profit For Each Currency in MQL4?

Tags: mql4

How can I Comment The Profit And Numbr Of Trade For Each Currency from Trade History?

for example in Screen , Show To me Like below Lines:

EURUSD :  Number Position = 5 , Profit = 31 $

GBPCAD : Number Position = 10 , Profit = -61 $

....

thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                              Ipek Bilgisayar.mq4 |
//|                                  Copyright 2023, MetaQuotes Ltd. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2023, MetaQuotes Ltd."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict

double eurusd=0,gbpusd=0,usdchf=0;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
   eurusd=KarHesapla("EURUSD");
   gbpusd=KarHesapla("GBPUSD");
   usdchf=KarHesapla("USDCHF");


   EkranaYazdir();
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void EkranaYazdir()
  {
   Comment("Ipek Bilgisayar",
           "\n","__________________________________",
           "\n","EURUSD \t:", eurusd,
           "\n","GBPUSD \t:", gbpusd,
           "\n","USDCHF \t:", usdchf
          );
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double KarHesapla(string Sembol)
  {
   double _karToplam=0;
   for(int i = 0; i < OrdersHistoryTotal(); i++)
     {
      if(OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY))
         if(OrderSymbol() == Sembol)
            _karToplam+= OrderProfit()+OrderSwap()+OrderCommission();
     }
   return _karToplam;
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```